# php field validation method not working

Tags: php, html

So I've got this weird problem I was wondering if I could get assistance on.

I have to write an all in one PHP page that a user enters a date into, as well as their hourly pay and wage, which is in turn calculated on a new php page through session data. If the user enters nothing in the required fields or does not enter a correct input, then it prints error messages.

My problem though is that even though I edited a project incredibly similar to this for my last assignment that worked fine, this handwritten one I've made does not register input fields correctly, and will always output the first error message that the validation method can print. I genuinely have no clue why this is happening, because it's so similar to the last project which worked just fine, I can't seem to find the problem.

Could anyone let me know if I'm doing something wrong? The error is coming from the second php code segment at the top where it prints error messages, and even if I post something in the field it just returns "Complete date is required". I've tried so many different variants of checking if the field is empty and all have failed, which leads me to believe it's not receiving the $_POST variables at all (I even called the page itself in the php forms. Also I know that the checkdate method most likely does not work, but it's not causing the issue so I'll fix it later.)

```
<?php // Session save

session_save_path
($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/sessiondata/");
session_start();
?>

<?php // validate_input()

// returns a string of error messages if invalid user input found or an empty string if no errors
function validate_input() {

    $errorMessages = "";

    // Confirm if user's entered date is correct
    if (!isset($_POST['month'], $_POST['day'], $_POST['year']))
        {
        $errorMessages .= "Complete date is required<br />";
        }
    elseif (!checkdate($_POST['month'], $_POST['day'], $_POST['year']))
        {
        $errorMessages .= "Incorrect date for pay period ending<br />";
        }

    return $errorMessages;
}
?>

<?php // Call validate_input()

// if this page has just called itself with user input data
//(i.e. the user pressed the submit button)
if (isset($_POST['submitButton'])) {
// validate the user input data
$error_messages = validate_input();

// if user input is valid, process the data and go to confirmation page
    if ($error_messages == "") {
        $_SESSION['hoursWorked'] = $_POST['hoursWorked']; // simplified processing
        $_SESSION['payRate'] = $_POST['payRate'];
        header('Location: getPay.php'); // go to confirmation page
        exit();
    }
    else {
        echo"<p>$error_messages</p>"; // show the error messages
    }
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<!--
Account: --------------
File: ----------------------
-->
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>CS 250: Program3</title>
<meta name="description" content="------" />
<meta name="keywords" content="------" />
<meta name="author" content="----" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="program3.css">
</head>

<body>

<div id="mainDiv">
<h1>Program 3</h1>

<!--First form - Pay period date fields-->
<form id="payPeriod" class="form" action="program3.php" method="post">
<fieldset>
<legend>Pay Period Ending</legend>

<!--3 input fields for dates aligned horizontally-->
<p>
<label for="month" class="label">Month</label>
<input id="month" name="month" type="text" size="5" />
<label for="day" class="label">Day</label>
<input id="day" name="day" type="text" size="5" />
<label for="year" class="label">Year</label>
<input id="year" name="year" type="text" size="5" />
* Required
</p>

</fieldset>
</form> <!--End of first form-->

<!--Second Form - Hours worked and pay rate-->
<form id="hoursRate" class="form" action="program3.php" method="post">
<fieldset>
<legend>Hours worked and pay rate</legend>

<!--Hours worked input field-->
<p>
<label for="hoursWorked" class="label">Hours worked</label>
<input id="hoursWorked" name="hoursWorked" type="text" size="20" />
* Required
</p>

<!--Pay rate input field-->
<p>
<label id="payRate" class="label">Pay rate</label>
<input id="payRate" name="payRate" type="text" size="20" />
* Required
</p>

</fieldset>
</form> <!--End of second form-->

<form id="subButton" action="program3.php" method="post">
<fieldset>
<!--Submit Button: Calculate Pay-->
<p id="button">
<input type="submit" id="submitButton" name="submitButton" value="Calculate Pay" />
</p>
</fieldset>
</form>

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Thank you in advance for any help. I seriously just don't know what's wrong with this anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your date field inputs are outside your `<form>` that is actually being POSTed, so they will not POST.  You need to have a single form if you want all these values POSTed at once.

Here is the form that is actually POSTed

```
<form id="subButton" action="program3.php" method="post">
<fieldset>
<!--Submit Button: Calculate Pay-->
<p id="button">
<input type="submit" id="submitButton" name="submitButton" value="Calculate Pay" />
</p>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

There are no input fields in it at all other than the submit.

You should really familiarize yourself with basic debugging techniques.  In this case even a rudimentary `var_dump($_POST)` at the top of the script would reveal that you are missing the input field data.

Comment: That actually sounds very likely. If that's the case, I have no clue why my professor is asking of us what he is - He formatted the example html page to have 3 seperate forms, the button being in its own form - by the looks of it for design purposes. Is it possible to embed a form within another form maybe? (Sorry, pretty new to PHP)

Comment: @Alzecha This is not specific to PHP. THis is basic HTML form functionality.  You can have multiple forms on a page, but you can only POST one at a time using basic HTTP POSTing methodology. Of course you would need a submit button to actually be able to perform a POST. It could be that your professor is a hack.

Comment: I guess from previous labs I came to assume forms and the post button could function together if given the same action, though what you're saying makes a lot more sense. I just have no clue how to replicate what he wants then, my best bet would be to just put it all in one form despite his given design

Comment: @Alzecha Yes. Discard his design.

Comment: It's a little messy at the moment but it definitely worked. Thanks a lot for the help, and my apologies for my lack of knowledge on debugging, I've never really had to do that with HTML before. I'll definitely read into it more.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a syntax error

```
 if (!isset($_POST['month'], $_POST['day'], $_POST['year']))
```

That should be written like

```
if (!isset($_POST['month']) && !isset($_POST['day']) && !isset($_POST['year']))
```

or

```
if (!(isset($_POST['month']) && isset($_POST['day']) && isset($_POST['year'])))
```

will be more convenient for me.

Comment: If you look at the `isset()` on the PHP manual, it allows for multiple values: http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

Comment: This was where I got confused, I was trying with multiple values in several different ways (The way my professor originally had it was !isset($_POST['data']) || empty($_POST['data']), at least in our last project. But that didn't work on this either. I tried using both || and && to seperate them, but neither worked

Answer (score 0):

If you want to validate separately, try modifying `elseif` to just `if` on the second statement:

```
function validate_input($errors = array()) {
    // Validate this set first
    if (!isset($_POST['month'], $_POST['day'], $_POST['year'])) {
            $errors[] = "Complete date is required";
        }

    // Validate this second, but not conditional on the first validating at all
    if (!checkdate($_POST['month'], $_POST['day'], $_POST['year'])) {
            $errors[] = "Incorrect date for pay period ending";
        }

    return implode("<br />",$errors).'<br />';
}
```

Comment: I'll try that, I'm just confused because what I posted is like a spitting image of our last project which worked just fine. It's almost like it's not taking the $_POST variables, but I just don't see how that's possible

Comment: Another thing I might need to mention: As a test I had it try and validate only one date input as being present, the month, and it still refused to acknowledge that anything was there.

Comment: As Mike Brant suggests, are you trying to validate all the fields on all your forms at once?

Comment: Not exactly, I was simply grouping error messages together based on the fields they pertain to, our professor said for the sake of smaller code we should put the date fields together in validation